# Authorization in ASP.NET MVC 2 using web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, web-config, authorization

I have an ASP.MVC 2 web page and I have my authentication done like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "fooPage" + user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), false, String.Empty);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Now I would like to set my web.config in a way that few pages can be only accessed if a user is authenticated. I have my web.config set like this:

```
<configuration>  
  <system.web>  
    <authentication mode="Forms">  
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" timeout="2880"/> //all users can access my web site  
    </authentication>  
    <authorization>  
      <allow users="*"/>  
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>  
  <location path="~/Views/Sales/Index.aspx">  
    <system.web>  
      <authorization>  
        <deny users="?"/> //only authenticated users can access this page  
      </authorization>  
    </system.web>  
  </location>  
</configuration>
```

... but this **does not** work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to put the `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller action:

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        // etc
```

You can also put the attribute on the controller instead of having to put it on every action method...

Edit in response to your comment: I don't know that it's possible to do natively using XML, but check out http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent324.aspx

Second edit, I've done some research and testing, and it is possible to use the default ASP.NET web.config stuff, use `<location path="~/Sales/Index">` instead of `<location path="~/Views/Sales/Index.aspx">`

**BUT**

you have to be really really careful if there's more than one URL that could land you on the same page, such as `/`, `/Home`, `/Home/`, `/Home/Index`, etc - you **won't** get the authorization settings on all of them automatically.  I think it's much safer to use something MVC-aware, such as the `[Authorize]` attribute, or the custom scheme I linked to above.

Comment: Yes I know, but is much easier to make changes to a web.config file rather than making changes in code.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I'll try your link.

Answer (score 6):

**Stop.**  If you try to use <location> in Web.config to secure an MVC application, you're at the very best making life difficult for yourself, and at the very worst opening up a gigantic security hole in your application.

As Jon alludes to, using [Authorize] or some other thing that correctly hooks the MVC pipeline (whether declarative or programmatic) is the *only* correct way of doing this.  The product team goes into more detail on this issue at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2010/08/24/securing-your-mvc-application.aspx.